# Series Lines and EndPoints with TeeChart

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart

Having a ChartSeries, I would like display a certain text on a label moving the mouse above the ChartValues. But only the line is active for me and not the EndPoint (definitely the Value…)
I would like if the EndPoint (a Circle, actually) would be active instead of the line and moving the mouse above this circle, my text can be appeared. Thanks.

Comment: provide your TeeChart version and edition

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MarkTips tool.
If you have a TLineSeries with Pointer.Visible=true, the mark tips tool will appear when you have the mouse over the line and over the pointer. If you only want it when you have the mouse over the series pointer, you could have a TLineSeries with Pointer.Visible=false and also a TPointSeries with the same data, and the MarkTips tool assigned to the TPointSeries.